# Hexagonal Grid Filling

Tags: grid-deduction

Fill in each blank white hexagon with a digit from 1 to 9. Each of the grey hexagons is the sum of the white hexagons around it, and all of the white hexagons that are around the same grey hexagon must be distinct.

[image]

The answer's already available, but I would like to see how people would logically solve this.

*Source: USAMTS*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Building on [shoover's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/83779/39654), solving it step by step:

- $30$ has 3 options, $[9, 8, \color{gray}{5}, 4, \color{gray}{3}, 1]$, $[9, 7, \color{gray}{5}, 4, \color{gray}{3}, 2]$ and $[8, 7, 6, \color{gray}{5}, \color{gray}{3}, 1]$ (with gray indicating already known). As $4$ and $6$ already exist around $21$, the box shared by $21$ and $30$ must be either $1$ or $2$.
- $26_{top}$ has 3 options, $[9, \color{gray}{6}, 5, 3, 2, 1]$, $[8, \color{gray}{6}, 5, 4, 2, 1]$ and $[7, \color{gray}{6}, 5, 4, 3, 1]$. Because $5$ already exists around $39$ the first option isn't applicable, and the two shared boxes with $39$ must be $4$ and $8/7$.
- This means that the bottom of $39$ must be $9 + (8/7)$, depending on which one is around $26_{top}$. There is no solution for $26_{bottom}$ if it is $9 + 8$, so it must be $9 + 7$. This means that $8$ is around $26_{top}$, and $26_{bottom}$ is $[9, 7, 4, 3, \color{gray}{2}, 1]$.

> [image]

- In all solutions for $30$ at this point, the only value it can share with $26_{bottom}$ beyond $9/7$ is $4$.
- Since $32$ already has a $1$, we can place the remaining numbers around $26_{bottom}$.
- Looking at the empty shared box between $32$ and $26_{top}$, the solution for $26_{top}$ dictates that this must be $5/2$. No solution exists for $32$ if its top-left box is $4$, so we can now place the $8/4$'s.

> [image]

- There's no solution for $32$ if it is $9 + 2$, $7 + 5$ or $7 + 2$, so it must be $9 + 5$ with a solution of $[9, \color{gray}{8}, 6, 5, \color{gray}{3, 1}]$. This also places the $9/7$'s and the remaining around $32$.
- The remaining boxes around $26_{top}$ are $2 + 1$. The only solution for $29$ is $[9, \color{gray}{6, 5, 4}, 3, 2]$, so their shared box must be $2$. This places the remaining around $26_{top}$.
- The remaining around $29$ are $9 + 3$. As $21$ cannot have a $9$, their shared box must be $3$. This places the remaining around $29$.

> [image]

- The remaining around $30$ are $9 + 2$. As $21$ cannot have $9$, this places the remaining blocks.

> [image]

Answer (score 12):

To get it started:

- $21$ has to be $1+2+3+4+5+6$
- $39$ has to be $9+8+7+6+5+4$
- $21$ already has a $4$, so the overlap between $21$ and $39$ has to be $5$ and $6$, but $29$ already has a $5$, so it must get the $6$, while $30$ shares the $5$. (The hex shared by $21$, $30$, and $39$ is $5$, and the hex shared by $21$, $29$, and $39$ is $6$.)

Answer (score 1):

This was really fun! After working it process of elimination after identifying max and min sums you can get from 6 digits 1-9, I was indeed able to solve.

I solved by saving image and notating like I would a Sudoku puzzle with possible choices. When in doubt, I would take combinations and choose absolute smallest or largest combinations between two hexagons and see if the rest of the cells were workable. This eliminated quite a few possibilities.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ym1CA.jpg

Comment: My apologies if you were asking for a mathematical proof, btw!